# PHP MySQL Insert Ignore Inserting Too Much Data

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a traffic exchange and every time a site is viewed I want it to insert in to a table which looks like:

-user
-site

The user is default of 1 and I don't insert in to it because I thought for an INSERT IGNORE you need a column that stays in the same.

My current query:

```
$db->Query("INSERT IGNORE INTO `surfed_site` (site) VALUES('".$sit['id']."')");
```

I have around 85 people online but in a 1 second refresh it goes from having 0 in the table to 750 which is impossible because a user has to view a site for 20seconds before it inserts.

I think my INSERT IGNORE isn't working, would anybody be able to guide me to see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you shure that surfed_site is a primary key ?

Comment: `surfed_site` is the table, how would I check?

Comment: sorry misread ... site i mean

Comment: `site` would need to have a unique/primary key on it to trigger the insert ignore. if it's a normal index, or not indexed at all, there's nothing to ignore, mysql will simply insert your new value.

Comment: check with phpmyadmin or another tool which shows you the table structure, if its not a key it won't work

Comment: Screenshots of the structure of surfed_site:

http://gyazo.com/bcb979484bcd87b3b070ead83bcf6d00.png

http://gyazo.com/69717ad8591110f729a0853ba60fa75c.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you shure that site is a primary key ?

In order to get INSERT IGNORE working you must declare the inserted value as primary / uniue key

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error is issued.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Add Primary Key if not existing with:

```
ALTER TABLE surfed_site ADD PRIMARY KEY (site);
```

Comment: ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);